# How to set up a pause for AWS EC2 spot requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I would like to use AWS EC2 spot requests for machine learning that I do in spots.

If you don't configure any settings for spot requests, they will be set to "fleet" and an EC2 instance will be created that cannot be paused (it can only be terminated).

If you know how to create an instance with a spot request that can be paused, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spot instances launched in a fleet can’t be paused or stopped. To stop a Spot instance, it must be launched by a Spot instance request for a single instance, you can create such requests using **Launch Instance** wizard, you may follow steps at this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-requests.html#create-spot-instance-request-console-procedure). Make sure to select "**Persistent request**" in the wizard.

This request will launch a Spot instance that can be **Stopped** but still can’t be **Paused**. Hibernate/Pause option is only available as a behavior at the event of interruption and can't be requested by the user.